# Ejecutables en Python

Tags: python

Disculpen lo que pasa es que quiero empaquetar una aplicación de PyQt5 con PyInstaller y me marca que se empaqueta correctamente pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación no se ejecuta nada y se cierra la aplicación, no se cual sea el error, por que al empaquetar con Tkinter si funciona, pero a la hora de empaquetar con PyQt5 no

Comment: Puedes añadir los pasos que estás haciendo para el empaquetado?

Answer (score -1):

El problema es justamente PyQt si lo hubieras hecho con Tkinter hubiera jalado. Lo que debes de hacer es desde la carpeta donde esta tu archivo usar el CMD (Simbolo de sistema) y ejecutar la siguiente linea:

```
pyuic5 nombre_archivo.ui -o nombre_archivo.py
```

También tienes que validar si es que usas otras librerías en tu código como pandas, si los "Hooks" estan habilitados en el PyInstaller. Te dejo un muy buen "link" de referencia:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIxSmELR7So

Comment: a va muchas gracias pero si ya compile el código de QTDesigner a código Python con el comando, y ya tengo todo en código Python y solo tengo librerías de PyQt5 el problema es que cuando lo empaqueto me marca todo como satisfactorio pero a la hora de ejecutar solo se cierra

Comment: incluso ya vi tres tutoriales donde empaquetan en Pyqt5 pero lo mas extraño es que, en los tutoriales si les corre todo bien , pero tambien intente empaquetar otras aplicaciones de Pyqt5 sencillas de solo una ventana y un componente pero tampoco me corren, la de tkinter si se ejecutan bien ya empaquetadas. Incluso ya hce todos los pasos de los tutoriales como por ejemplo ejecutar el comando de el ejecutable en los scripts pero tampoco